# How to have a full width image in WhatsApp shared link

Tags: metadata, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

I want to be able to have different images of the shared link preview especially with WhatsApp's  want a full-width image like the one of youtube

I tried images with different dimensions. But not working.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Https://linearc.top/image1. Jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="Https://linearc.top/image2. Jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="Https://linearc.top/image3. Jpg">
```

I want to be able to have something like this[image]

I instead of 
[image]